# Counting the number of rows in a document and then printing the number on another excel file

Tags: excel, vba

Basically, people in my team list things daily. I want to count the number of lists (the rows) for each day and copy it into a separate file. So it looks like this:

```
Date          count 
01.01.2022    40 
02.01.2022    89
```

etc

I know how to count rows using VBA but no idea how to print the number in another file.

Comment: `Workbooks("otherfile").Worksheets("sheetname").Range("A1").Value = theCount`?

Comment: HI thanks for this. How do I make sure that it connects with the row count I've just done (so I set count as a variable)? And also, so it prints line by line (offsets downwards)

Comment: `theCount` is your variable. For your second question, see [how to find the last row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba).